# Why is the nose cone of Russian fighters pointing slightly down?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, fighter, russia, su-30

Let's take the [Sukhoi Su-30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukhoi_Su-30) as an example:

[image: Sukhoi Su-30]

The nose cone is clearly pointing a bit downwards with respect to the level of the engines and wings. Why is this? How can this kind of banana even fly properly?

Here's the profile an F/A-18 for comparison:

[image: F/A-18]

Comment: +1 for calling it a banana.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nose cone position depends upon the mission profile of the aircraft. [Su-30 is a multirole fighter for all-weather, air-to-air and air-to-surface deep interdiction missions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukhoi_Su-30), since its air-surface with deep interdiction it needs to have a view of the ground while targeting ground troops/equipments/artillery. This nose down config helps it to have that view. F-18/F-16/F-15 are air superiority aircrafts. Yes same cannot be said for F-18 but then F-18 has many variants, F-18D which has air-ground support is slightly elevated pilot view for better ground view. Same can be seen in Eurofighter Typhoon and A-10 Thunderbolt.

While Su-15, Su-24 and Mig-27 where interceptors and bombers, they have straight nose just like their companions from the west.

Comment: Same principle was applied to Concorde nose, due to its long nose pilot wasn't able to see the runway. So they developed a way to lower its nose while taxi. This is beautifully demonstrated in this video (starts at 5:05 ) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2oiv4249sRU

Comment: I would like to know how this affects aerodynamics.

Comment: It makes SU-30 longitudinally unstable or we can say "relaxed stability".

Comment: The F-18 is properly the F/A-18, with the A for Attack. Ground attack. It was dual role from its inception, and is not considered a pure air superiority fighter. (*Consider the aircraft it replaced...*) Also, you don’t strafe from straight and level flight, you dive when attacking the ground, so tilting the nose down to see what you’re attacking doesn’t make sense.